# Stagevideo stream from youtube

Tags: video, air, stage3d

Is it possible to stream a video from Youtube to a stagevideo instance i.e. not embedding it in a stageWebView instance.

Comment: I've done it. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem, I have no implementation yet. I'm after knowing if it's possible (you've confirmed that it is) and info of the the process involved would be great. For example do I need to sign up for the youtube API system or did get detail of a video from looking at the browser requests etc? Thanks for the info above :)